# Ruby on Rails passing of parameters between views (not all being transferred)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I've been trying to trace this error for nearly 2 days now and I can't seem to understand what is going wrong. I'll explain:

I have 2 views (.html.erb format)
ViewA has the following

`<% form_tag (:action => 'ViewB') do %>`

I have on this page a 
select_tag `radius`

text_field_tag `searchQuery` (disabled as is filled in already),

text_field_tag `subSearch`

text_field_tag `LAT`
`<%= text_field_tag  'LAT', "", :disabled => true, :size => 15, :id =>'LAT'   %>`

and another identical to LAT named LNG instead

and lastly a submit_tag `Locate`

When ViewB is being loaded, I am noticing the following from the ruby console:

```
  Parameters: {"subSearch"=>"Management Consultants", "commit"=>"Locate", "authenticity_token"=>"XXJ+sfl2HkoInaj/1fNtIYpVLJ4NjTjJHY2oe18RPXs=", "radius"=>"5"}
```

I cant understand why the other parameters are not being passed! Although they are disabled I believe this should effect them from being transmitted, (I have tried re-enabling them to no avail).

Does anyone have any ideas please? What am I doing wrong? I really require the Lat and Lng!

Comment: Disabled controls aren't submitted to the server (they aren't 'successful' in the language of the HTML spec). Are you sure they didn't get submitted when they were enabled?

Comment: oh my your right, re-enabling them did resolve the issue. I was sure i re-checked them! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the controls disabled and still submit the values, you could use hidden inputs in addition to the disabled text controls:

```
hidden_field_tag('LAT', '', :id => 'LAT_hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Phil Ross, the answer was to enable them! silly me!